# Help with JSON iteration

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a JSON response, but this doesn't seem to work:

My javascript code:

```
  function recommend(response){

    var recommendedList = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');

    $H(recommendedList).each(function(item){
          alert(item.artist);
        });     
  }
```

What I want is to retrieve each artist values from the JSON response.

and the JSON response is of the format:

```
[
 {"artist":"artist1","location":{"lat":"50.952226","lng":"5.34832","ID":28}},
 {"artist":"artist2","location":{"lat":"52.362287","lng":"4.883965","ID":32}},
  ...
]
```

A little help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: `$H()`... is that [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)? BTW, do **not** use `eval()` like that, it's a gaping security hole and source of bugs.

Comment: Also, I think `$H()` expects an object as input, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from the "$H()" that you're using prototype, I'd just get rid of that "$H()" because the array should already be iterable.

```
recommendedList.each(function(item) {
  alert(item.artist);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your `$H()` function is supposed to be doing (and its existence [makes me very sad](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/720)), but this framework-agnostic snippet seems to get the job done:

```
for (var index = 0; index < recommendedList.length; index++) {
    alert(recommendedList[index].artist);
}
```

Here is a working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/VgPy5/

Also, I'm sure you're going to be chastised for using `eval()` like that.  You might consider using [JSON.parse()](http://www.json.org/js.html) instead.

Comment: The "$H()" thing is almost certainly from the Prototype framework.

Comment: Thanks for the JSON.parse() tip.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid framework features when you need simple things.

```
for(i=0; i<recommendedList.length; i++) { 
    alert(recommendedList[i].artist);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.prototypejs.org/api/hash/each

> Pairs are passed as the first argument of the iterator, in the form of
>   objects with two properties:
>
> key, which is the key name as a String
>
> value, which is the corresponding value (and can, possibly, be undefined)

So your `item` is actually the key. Instead, iterate like:

```
$H(recommendedList).each(function(key, item){
      alert(item.artist);
    });
```

Comment: @Pointy: I'm not sure but I was trying to point out what was happening. Your solution is preferable indeed.